# Bash: how to redirect continuous output to text file but make lines unique?

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

Ok, I have this line that outputs data to a text file.  The only issue is I need the lines to be unique.  So, if it is going to add a line that already exists how can I prevent that?  This is my script:

```
 tcpdump -lvi any "udp port 53" 2>/dev/null|grep -E 'A\?'|awk '{print $(NF-1)}' >> /tmp/domains
```

Do I pipe it go awk and somehow delete duplicates?  Do I have another script run everyone minute that removes duplicates?

Here is the output of loading up Amazon.com:

```
 amazon.com.
 amazon.com.
 www.amazon.com.
 www.amazon.com.
 amazon.com.
 www.amazon.com.
 a0e90b2a1701074fb52d450dc80084cb1.labs.cloudfront.net.
 a0e90b2a1701074fb52d450dc80084cb1.labs.cloudfront.net.
 ad.doubleclick.net.
 ad.doubleclick.net.
 ecx.images-amazon.com.
 ...more
```

And in looking at my output it looks like I need to figure out why there is a trailing dot.

Comment: Aaaaand cue the pain...

Answer (score 2):

You never need grep AND awk since awk can do anything grep can do so if you're using awk, just use awk:

```
tcpdump -lvi any "udp port 53" 2>/dev/null|
awk '/A\?/{ key=$(NF-1); if (!seen[key]++) print key }' > /tmp/domains
```

If you ever need to stop this script and restart it but only append new domains to the output file, you just need to read the output file first to populate the "seen" array, e.g.:

```
tcpdump -lvi any "udp port 53" 2>/dev/null|
awk -v outfile="/tmp/domains" '
    BEGIN{
        while ( (getline key < outfile) > 0 )
            seen[key]++
        close(outfile)
    }
    /A\?/{ key=$(NF-1); if (!seen[key]++) print key >> outfile }
'
```

Comment: +1: might be cleaner to avoid getline and do something like `awk 'NR==FNR{ seen[$0]=1; next } ... ' /tmp/domains -`

Comment: If I'd done that then I'd have had to account for the possibility of the file being empty (so `NR==FNR` wouldn't work) and I've had to copy /tmp/domains to a temp input file and remove it again later (since `awk '...' file - > file` could zap `file` before reading it). This is one of those rare cases where `getline` is actually appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This will print out only unseen input lines as they come in, rather than at the end like some other duplicate removing awk scripts posted.

```
awk '{host=$(NF-1)} !(host in list) {print host; list[host]++}'
```

If you only want to run the whole thing periodically and update the list, it may be easier to do something like

```
tcpdump and extract hostnames | sort -u /tmp/domains - > /tmp/domains.new
mv /tmp/domains.new /tmp/domains
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
tcpdump -lvi any "udp port 53" 2>/dev/null|grep -E 'A\?'|awk '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

To:

```
tcpdump -lvi any "udp port 53" 2>/dev/null|grep -E 'A\?'|awk '{a[$(NF-1)]++}END{for(i in a)print i}'
```

Comment: That looks interesting but how is it supposed to write out to the text file?  I want it to continuously update the text file.

Answer (score 0):

Hrmm, do you need a list of domains (unique)? Or do you need the whole line?

You could try using the whole line as a key in the awk array, but the timestamps will be different, and packetsizes, etc.

```
gawk 'BEGIN{count=0} {arr[$0]=$(NF-1); if (length(arr) > count) { count++; print $0 )}'domain
```

though likely more useful to you is lines for each domain...

```
gawk '{ domain = $(NF-1); arr[ domain ] = $0 ;}  
    END {  for (entry in arr) print "domain:",entry, arr[entry]} '
```

some output would have been useful to see.
ok, I see the output now,

**Domains MUST end in a dot** Good Luck!!

ps. use this one

```
cmd | gawk 'BEGIN{ count = 0 } { 
             arr[ $0 ] = $(NF-1); 
             if (length(arr) > count) { 
                 count++; 
                 print $0 
             }
      }'
```

as it continuously adds new domains to the output. Better to not lookup domains and use ips instead...

```
replace $(NF-1) with |& host -t A domain  or so
```

see Advanced Features :: Two-Way pipelines in the gawk info pages 'info gawk'

For it to be useful you need to insert the new domains into a sorted list. While I don't suggest using ncurses for this, piping the output to a java program that shows the data in a single, sorted table would be not *too* hard...

Comment: I need a unique list of domains.  I'll update the question with output.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you plan on running this for a long time or have a very busy site, you could ensure uniqueness by saving previous lookups to an awk hash. This works here:

```
tcpdump -lvi any "udp port 53" 2> /dev/null | grep -E 'A\?' | awk '!h[$(NF-1)]++ { print $(NF-1) }' > /tmp/domains
```

Otherwise, you need to save chunks of the `tcpdump/grep` output to a temporary file and merge it with `/tmp/domains`. The best way I know is to keep the output sorted individually and then do a unique merge-sort with `sort -mu`. This works here:

```
lim=10000
tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/unique.domain.XXXXXX)
unique_domains=/tmp/domains

tcpdump -lvi any "udp port 53" 2> /dev/null | grep -E 'A\?' | while read line; do
  awk -v lim=$lim '!h[$(NF-1)]++ { print $(NF-1); ndomain++ }; ndomain > lim { exit }' | sort > $tmpfile
  sort -mu $tmpfile $unique_domains 2> /dev/null > $unique_domains.tmp
  mv $unique_domains.tmp $unique_domains
done
```

If you want to access `/tmp/domain` while this is running you need to add some file locking, for example with `lockfile`:

```
lim=10000
lock=/tmp/domains.lock
tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/unique.domain.XXXXXX)
unique_domains=/tmp/domains

tcpdump -lvi any "udp port 53" 2> /dev/null | grep -E 'A\?' | while read line; do 
  awk -v lim=$lim '!h[$(NF-1)]++ { print $(NF-1); ndomain++ }; ndomain > lim { exit }' | sort > $tmpfile
  lockfile $lock
  sort -mu $tmpfile $unique_domains 2> /dev/null > $unique_domains.tmp
  mv $unique_domains.tmp $unique_domains
  rm $lock
done
```

Now to get a snapshot of `/tmp/domains` you would do something like this:

```
lockfile /tmp/domains.lock
cp /tmp/domains unique_domains
sync
rm -f /tmp/domains.lock
```

Comment: This will be running constantly on a linux proxy.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer:

Here is a solution using a pipe to the bash function

```
checkDuplicates() {
    touch -- "$1" # Where $1 is a file that holds the data. It could be the same file that you write to or any other one.
    while read -r nextCheck; do
        grep -q -m 1 "$nextCheck" "$1" || printf "%s\n" "$nextCheck"
    done
}

myFile='/tmp/domains'
YOURANYCOMMAND | checkDuplicates "$myFile" > "$myFile"
```

### Bonus trick:

This could be useful for the case when you want to see a difference between two files. For example:
`fileA:`

```
what
is
this
```

`fileB:`

```
what
I
is
dont
this
even
```

Then this code

```
cat 'fileB' | checkDuplicates 'fileA'
```

Is going to output

```
I
Dont
Even
```

Comment: `cat fileA | awk 'NR==FNR{seen[$0]++;next} !seen[$0]' - fileB` is the simpler, more robust way to do that (assming `cat fileA` represents some piped output and isn't literally intended to be a UUOC) and never do `cmd file > file`.